# SSIS Package ODBC Destination : Unknown column 'id' in 'field list';

Tags: ssis, mariadb, odbc, etl, database-administration

I am setting up a pipeline between two remote servers, in the Destination tools I choose the connection and the table, but when clicking on Mappings I get the following error:

[image]

What is frustrating is that there is no 'id' column either on the source or destination table...

I am using the MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver.
I have other pipelines and they work really well with the same Source and destination Servers.

I tried to re-create the tables with this problem but it doesn't change anything. The same thing happens when I try to use that particular table as an ODBC Source...

Any Ideas?

Comment: Double click the line between the ODBC Destination and the previous component. On the  Metadata tab, take a screenshot showing the path metadata. This should be a list of all the columns available to the downstream components. Please update your question with that data so we can attempt to reproduce your issue

Comment: @billinkc I create new tables with the same column names... it seems to work now. but I still have no idea why that message was showing up

Comment: @HamzaHamdani mostly this is caused by some developed triggers.

Comment: @Hadi my thought is, when I created the table the first I set the column 'id' as a primary key and index but then I deleted that table so maybe there's no more 'id' column but the index is still there ? Could it be this ?

Answer (score 0):

> I create new tables with the same column names... it seems to work now. but I still have no idea why that message was showing up

Mainly, there is a trigger on the table `tech` where the column `id` is used. This will keep throwing the exception `Unknown column ...`. This is why creating a new table solved your issue.

---

#### Helpful links:

- [UNOBVIOUS "UNKNOWN COLUMN IN 'FIELD LIST'" ERROR](https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2015/07/16/unobvious-unknown-column-in-field-list-error/)
- [Exception from HRESULT: 0xC020204A Connecting to MySQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/355579/exception-from-hresult-0xc020204a-connecting-to-my.html)

Comment: my thought is, when I created the table the first I set the column 'id' as a primary key and index but then I deleted that table so maybe there's no more 'id' column but the index is still there ? Could it be this ?